# Which event intercepts the change of selection of the row (or element) in a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, qtableview

I would like to know which event allows me to intercept the change of focus in a QTableView.

I tried with the `keyPressEvent` which allows me to intercept keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd>, but does not allow me to intercept the keyboard arrows to move from one line to another.

In simple terms, what I'm trying to do is to change an image when I move from one element to another in the table view with keyboard arrows. I don't need to know how to change the image, but only what event to use to intercept, or otherwise perceive the change of selection from the table view.

I searched [the official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/). I read something about QItemSelectionModel, but I can't understand how to create this event. With `keyPressEvent`, I can't intercept the arrow up and down.

Comment: The fact that you use Qt Creator is almost irrelevant, but you never specified a much more important aspect: are you talking about Qt Widgets or QtQuick/QML? Qt provides [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html) for the former, and [TableView QML element](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) for the latter; while conceptually similar, their usage and implementation is quite different, and we cannot answer you without knowing that fundamental aspect.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)` signal of the table-view's `selectionModel()` ?

Comment: It's Qt widgets

Comment: Then connect the related signals of the view's [`selectionModel()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel): [`currentChanged`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) is probably what you're interested into. Check the section about [handling selections of items](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-of-items) in the model/view programming docs, then, if you still have issues [edit] your post to provide a [mre] of your attempts. For future reference, please ensure that you provide the important details and use correct terminology.

Comment: Resolved.
I put in mainwindow.h under private slots:

void slotSelectionChange(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected);

I set the connection in the form load and in the various events:

connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)),SLOT(slotSelectionChange(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)));


So I intercepted the event in the slot:

void MainWindow::slotSelectionChange(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)
{
//I wrote my code here
}

Comment: Sorry for my bad english